# Crystal Reports - repeat page header when data changes

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I have a report that is pretty complex, with multiple sub-reports for each item selected.  I want a main header for each item, and then a page header for that item at the top of each page.  If I only select one item it looks great.  If I have multiple items, that main page header only shows once.

```
main header
page header item 1
details

page header item 1
details

page header item 1
details

main header
page header item 2
details

page header item 2
details
```

How do I design it so that Item 2 main header shows up?

The details are a series of group headers (I inherited this report).  Right now it has just what I want, except that the main header shows once and only once.  It is in a Report Header section, the page header is a Page Header section, and all the rest of the reports (which can span multiple pages) are in various Group Header sections.

**edit:**
I can put both the main header and the page header in a Page Header a and Page Header b section, with the item id in both.  Now, if I can suppress Page Header a if item id is duplicated, it should print it only with a new item id, and the page header b will still print at the top of each page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since a report only has one "Report Header", you'll have to organize your groups in a way that "main header" is a top level group, "page header" is a sub group, and finally details is below that.

Once you have that done you can then click on the **Paging tab** in **section expert** and click the **New Page Before** option in order to get the pages to break like you expect.

**Edit:**
Under menu Report, Group Export, in the Group By, there is an Options button, and then an Options tab.  That is where the Repeat Group Header on Each Page option is.  Then, back in the Section Expert for the Main Header Group, in the Suppress function, put InRepeatedGroupHeader.  That way, the Main Header (GroupHeader#1a) is suppressed except for the first page for each item, and the Page Header (GroupHeader#1b) shows at the top of each page.

Comment: I made a GroupHeader#1a with the main header and that works.  My page header is a GroupHeader#2a and it does not show on each page.  How do I make a Group Header show at the top of each page?

Comment: Right click on the GroupHeader2A bar and select 'Section Expert'.  Then click on the paging tab, and select 'New Page Before'.

Comment: I made a typo above: the sections are GroupHeader#1a and 1b (not 2a), with additional groups starting at 2a.

Comment: Nonetheless, if I have a New Page Before the second group, it doesn't make that group show at the top of each page.  It just makes a main header on a page by itself (because I already have New Page Before GroupHeader#1a)

Comment: It sounds like your sort order is wrong for print order.  The records controlling print order should appear in the same logical order as the order in which you want them to print.  Your groups should follow this same order?  If your grouping logic makes this impossible then I'm out of ideas for you.

Comment: The data is displaying in the correct order now, it just isn't printing a new report header when the item changes.  Which it wouldn't, since it is a report header.

Comment: Ok, cool.  There should be an option that says something to the effect of repeat group header with each group change or something like that.  I'm not at my dev station anymore so I can't verify exact syntax.  Google it and I'm sure you'll find it.

Comment: I wish I could give this an upvote again.  New job, new problem, same solution.

Answer (score 0):

IN the grouping there are two Headers i.e. 1- Report Header (a, b, c etc) and 2- Page Header. Place the Fields (column names) in the Report Header and also the Same Fields (columns Names) in the Page Header. 
Then in the Group Expert , Check the Radio Button in the Group Option to : "Repeat the Group Header on Each Page". 
The Report Header fields will be displayed on the first Page and Page Header will be displayed on the rest of Pages.

Answer (score 0):

I got my answer from this [external post by brucevde on VB Forums](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?246703-How-to-repeat-records-in-4-column-in-a-same-sheet-in-crystal-report&p=1445784#post1445784):

> What you need to do is setup your details section for multiple
>      columns.
>
> Place the database field(s) in the details section as normal. 
>   In Format Section dialog, click on Details and an option appears at the bottom called **"Format with Multiple Columns"**. 
>   Once you check this option a new tab called Layout will appear. Use this tab to setup your multi-column page.
>
> When you click OK, Crystal will duplicate your details section to the right X number of times, depending on the width you have chosen.
>   Reply With Quote Reply With Quote